# Read from generated csv file in memory without writing to hard disk using `scan_csv`

Tags: python-polars

`numpy` supports reading from `StringIO`. I can create a string representation of csv and feed it to `numpy`.

How to do it in `pypolars`?

I came to know that I can use `read_csv()` with `lazy()`, but I want to use `scan_csv` to get the benefits of lazy eval. How to go about doing that?

EDIT: Updated question to specify `scan_csv`.

Comment: Are you saying `io.StringIO` doesn't work? `pl.read_csv(io.StringIO("1,2,3,4\na,b,c,d"))` or `pl.read_csv(b"1,2,3,4\na,b,c,d")`?

Comment: @jqurious I always use `scan_csv()`. Didn't think about using `read_csv()`. But why does `scan_csv()` not allow string objects?

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps it makes sense to change your question to explictly mention `.scan_csv`